# How can I dynamically create Firebase Firestore Cloud Function queries?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to dynamically generate queries.

I have a big object of things like location and price data. But I get that data from the request. How can I dynamically make use of that data if every query thing is a chained function?

Ideally I'd like to convert something like this...

```
const wheres = [
  { key: 'price', operator: '>=', value: '1000' },
  { key: 'price', operator: '<=', value: '2000' }
]
```

...to...

```
admin
      .firestore()
      .collection(`rentals`)
      .where(`price`, `>=`, `1000`)
      .where(`price`, `<=`, `2000`)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to chain everything *directly* with each other.  The builder pattern used to build the query returns an instance of [Query](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/Query) with each call to [where()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/CollectionReference#where) (and other filtering methods).  The code you wrote is equivalent to this:

```
const collection = admin.firestore().collection('rentals')
var query = collection.where('price', '>=', '1000')
query = query.where('price', '<=', '2000')
```

You can keep working with `query` as much as you want like this.  So, you should be able to keep appending more constraints to it in a loop or whatever suits your requirements.

Comment: very useful, in mi case My query end up something like:
let query = this.collection.where('active', '==', true)
      .where('house', '==', filters.houseAddress)

    if (filters.houseUrl) {
      query = query.where('houseUrl', '==', filters.houseUrl)
    }

    const results = await query.get()

Comment: Hi Doug! could you update this code to Firebase v9? thanks!